# Adding multi-lines into one list?

Tags: python

I have multi-lines of Emails and I need to do a couple of things:

```
stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za
louis@media.berkeley.edu
zqian@umich.edu
rjlowe@iupui.edu
zqian@umich.edu
rjlowe@iupui.edu 
... etc
```

1. I need to put them in one list:     `['stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za','louis@media.berkeley.edu','louis@media.berkeley.edu'`..etc`]`
2. need to figure out which Email is the most repetitive within that list, That's how I startred my code and I hope I could complete it from where I ended my code!

   ```
   fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
   if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "mbox-short.txt"
   fh = open(fname)
   lines = []
   count = 0 # For next step
   for line in fh:
       line = line.rstrip()
       if not line.startswith("From ") : continue
       x = line.split()
       emails = x[1]
    #print y

   maxapperence = 0 
   famous = None
   for mail in emails:
       count = emails.count(mail)
       if count > maxapperence:
           famous = mail
   print famous

   apparence = dict()
   for mail in set(emails):
       apparence[mail] = emails.count(mail)
   print apparence]
   ```

   out put :

   ```
   stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za
   louis@media.berkeley.edu
   zqian@umich.edu
   rjlowe@iupui.edu
   zqian@umich.edu
   rjlowe@iupui.edu
   cwen@iupui.edu
   cwen@iupui.edu
   gsilver@umich.edu
   gsilver@umich.edu
   zqian@umich.edu
   gsilver@umich.edu
   wagnermr@iupui.edu
   zqian@umich.edu
   antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk
   gopal.ramasammycook@gmail.com
   david.horwitz@uct.ac.za
   david.horwitz@uct.ac.za
   david.horwitz@uct.ac.za
   david.horwitz@uct.ac.za
   stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za
   louis@media.berkeley.edu
   louis@media.berkeley.edu
   ray@media.berkeley.edu
   cwen@iupui.edu
   cwen@iupui.edu
   cwen@iupui.edu
   ```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python

Comment: Look into `collections.Counter` https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a file that only contains email addresses:

```
import collections
filename = ''
c = collections.Counter(map(str.strip, open(filename).readlines()))
print(c.most_common(10)) # dumb example of possible output format
```

Comment: Sorry maybe I should have said that from the beginning, but actually I've extracted those email addresses from a txt file!

Comment: @Khalida If you already have email adresses in a list, you can replace `map(....)` in my example with your list: `l = ['a@b.c', 'd@e.f']; c = collections.Counter(l)`

Comment: No the emails where not in a list but just in plain text file.

Comment: Then my answer should be good enough I think? Just set `filename`

Comment: I don't need to go back to file name, I've already extracted the emails and they print like above , Now I need to put them in one list and loop through the list to find the most in the list and how many times exist there?

Comment: @Khalida: That code seems invalid, `emails` is a string that gets overwritten for each iteration, and in the second loop you treat it as a list. If it were a list, you could just `c = collections.Counter(emails)`. I'm sorry but I'm not sure I can help you any more if you don't get what I'm saying over and over again.

Comment: Never mind, I solved the problem by myself , Thanks to all .

Answer (score 0):

First example

```
emails = """stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za
louis@media.berkeley.edu
zqian@umich.edu
rjlowe@iupui.edu
zqian@umich.edu
rjlowe@iupui.edu
cwen@iupui.edu
cwen@iupui.edu
gsilver@umich.edu
gsilver@umich.edu
zqian@umich.edu
gsilver@umich.edu
wagnermr@iupui.edu
zqian@umich.edu
antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk
gopal.ramasammycook@gmail.com
david.horwitz@uct.ac.za
david.horwitz@uct.ac.za
david.horwitz@uct.ac.za
david.horwitz@uct.ac.za
stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za
louis@media.berkeley.edu
louis@media.berkeley.edu
ray@media.berkeley.edu
cwen@iupui.edu
cwen@iupui.edu
cwen@iupui.edu""".split("\n")

maxapperence = 0 
famous = None
for mail in set(emails):
    count = emails.count(mail)
    if count > maxapperence:
        famous = mail
        maxapperence = count
print famous, maxapperence
```

You can also store all mail apparence

```
apparence = dict()
for mail in set(emails):
    apparence[mail] = emails.count(mail)
print apparence
```

Comment: I have saved the whole emails in 'y'

Comment: Hi wilfriedrt, I'm getting very close, I just need to show the number of times  that Email exist on that list , at the moment the out-put is showing : cwen@iupui.edu  while it should be:  cwen@iupui.edu  5 as the Email exist 5 times on that list, I tried to use the count = 0 within the  same loop but it didn't loop through ! please help .

Comment: You just have to use maxappereance since it's used to store the max number of apparence.